# Simple Jquery Hover Issue

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have some very simple jquery as listed below:

```
$(".block").hover(function(){
    $(".drag").stop().fadeIn(1000);                
}, function(){
    $(".drag").stop().fadeOut(1000);
});
```

I have a series of divs, each having a class of `block`. When I hover over `.block`, `.drag` fades in ALL of the divs with a class of block. I just want the `.drag` to be faded in on the element that the mouse is hovering over, not all of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that the `.drag` element you want is a descendant of the element hovered over:

```
$(".block").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".drag").stop().fadeIn(1000);                
}, function(){
    $(this).find(".drag").stop().fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: should be set to stop(true,true) to avoid some buggy behavior

Answer (score 1):

How about using delegate?

You can't use hover though, you need mousein and mouseout [JQuery API -> Delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).  The API docs specifically mention the hover event.

```
 // something more specific than body would probably be good, but some 
 // common parent of these divs
 $('body').delegate('.block', 'mousein', function() {
     $(this).find(".drag").stop().fadeIn(1000); 
 });

 $('body').delegate('.block', 'mouseout', function() {
     $(this).find(".drag").stop().fadeOut(1000);
 });
```

Comment: good thought, but the above answer is just what I was looking for. I would use this if I needed the benefits of using .live

Comment: I guess you're right.  Just thought I'd throw it in.  Glad you got your answer @JCHASE11!